# Bridge in $3$-regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

Prove that a $3$-regular graph with a bridge has at least $10$ vertices.

The solution I was given uses Havel-Hakimi theorem. I tried to do it without using it :

I suppose that $G$ is connected, I don't know if I am allowed to do it. By contradiction, suppose that the number of vertices $p$ is less than $10$. The handshaking-lemma gives $3p=2q$ ($q$ is the number of edges) meaning that $p$ is even and since any vertex in $G$ has degree 3, then $p \geq 4$. This implies that $p \in \{4,6,8\}$.

If $p=4$, then removing the bridge leaves the graph $G-e$ with two connected components that have either $1$ and $3$ vertices or $2$ and $2$ vertices each. In the first scenario, the isolated vertex when added $e$ has $1$ edge in $G$, contradiction. Same thing for the 2nd scenario, one of the two vertices in a connected component will have degree $1$.

If $p=6$, same thing : we'll either have $"1-5"$ division, $"2-4"$ or "$3-3$". The latter is the new case, and adding $e$ to a vertex in a connected component makes others have degree $2$ at most. Contradiction.

If $p=8$, same thing again with new case $4-4$ division. We can convince ourselves again that a vertex will have a degree $<3$ in one of the components.

Is this okay ? To solve the issue that I assumed $G$ to be connected, I actually know that if $p=4$ or $6$, then $G$ must be connected if $3$-regular. For $p=8$, $G$ can be the union of two $3$-regular $(4, 6)$ graphs so disconnected...

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ be the property "$3$-regular and fewer than $10$ vertices". If a graph with property $P$ is disconnected, it is easy to see that one of its connected components also has property $P$. Thus it suffices to show that no connected graph has property $P$.

The handshaking lemma shows that the number of vertices on one side of the bridge has to be odd. Any partition of an even number less than $10$ into two odd parts has a $3$-or-less part (by pigeonhole); it is also easy to show that no $3$-regular graph on $1$ or $3$ vertices can reside on one side of the bridge. This concludes the proof.